# Документация для получения сертификата качества разработанной системы ПО

Tags: проектирование, документация

Как разработать документацию для получения сертификата качества разработанной системы ПО. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Cертификат качества разработанной системы ПО? А это что вообще такое?

Comment: да хрен знает, я поэтому и спрашиваю)

Comment: Ну подождите - это вообще что-то реально существующее? Вам же судя по вопросу зачем-то понадобился этот сертификат качества, е так ли? Я, например, впервые о таком слышу. Собственно, отсюда вопрос - стоит ли вообще как-то заморачиваться ради получения  какого-то ненужного и неизвестного сертификата?

Comment: Это у меня лаба такая) в интернете ничего не нашел

Comment: ну тогда вам имеет смысл спросить об этом у вашего преподавателя - что именно он имел в виду и что именно он хочет от вас получить. В реальной разработке, я, боюсь, не существует подобных сертификатов.

Comment: Взять, да самому придумать этот сертификат)

Comment: Не знаю, как насчет сертификата качества ПО, а вот [сертификат качества ISO 9001](http://www.rospromtest.ru/content.php?id=254) для фирмы иногда требуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я приводил характеристики ПО (функциональность, надежность, эффективность...) и доказывал, почему моя программа подходит под них. Отчет приняли. Спасибо за помощь.